# How do I use testcafe-hammerhead behind a load balancer that implements HTTPS?

Tags: testcafe

Our public facing domain that will implement the web proxy has the SSL implementation behind a load balancer, this works fine however the website that's being proxied will now try to call resources via HTTP (because the proxy server still runs as http), this causes a Mixed Content error.

[Mixed Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwIru.png)

I've tried starting the http server using the `https-playground` flag, however since the SSL is handled by the load balancer we don't necessarily have the certificate and key, and we don't actually *need* testcafe-hammerhead to start a HTTPS server either, but the calls that are being made by the webpage should just have HTTPS as the scheme.